# Расцвет аббревиатур как явление в языке

Tags: аббревиатуры

Мне кажется, что время после Октябрьской революции - это период расцвета в языке всевозможных аббревиатур. Вспомним: ВЧК, ВКП(б), НЭП - сокращали до размеров аббревиатур все, что только можно. А если не аббревиатур, то просто сокращали: Совмин, ликбез, нардеп. По этой аналогии я долгое время в детстве был уверен, что название поселка в Крыму Мисхор - это тоже подобное сокращение))))
Так вот, действительно ли это чисто послереволюционное явление и откуда оно вообще взялось в русском языке. Зачем все слова стали урезать?

Comment: А  в  Англии,  Америке,  Франции  и  т.п. -  там  как ?

Answer (score 4):

Сокращать слова и превращать фразы в аббревиатуры первыми додумались древние римляне (?)
SPQR - сенат и народ римский;
STTL - пусть земля тебе будет пухом;
P.S. - после написанного;
NB! - заметь хорошо!
и многие другие.
Очевидно, что все это использовалось в письменной форме папирусов и пергаментов экономии для. Короче, вслух аббревиатуры не выговаривались, да и кому это было надо?
Христиане подхватили культурную римскую эстафету и создали всемирно-известную сокращенную надпись :
[image: INRI]

На православных иконах можно найти множество сокращений (МЛРБ, ГА, ГГ и тп.)
Сокращение Е.И.В. (Его Императорское Величество) чаще всех применялось в царской России - в документах, прессе...
УОЛЕ - Уральское общество любителей естествознания, основано в 1870.
Жизнь при "проклятом царизме" была достаточно размеренной и неторопливой, поэтому сокращали относительно немного. Революция ускорила этот процесс - в одночасье появились сотни новых понятий, названий и учреждений, а бумаги и времени сильно не хватало. Стали активно сокращать и **произносить** буквально все подряд. Вместо армии появилась РККА, вместо правительства - СНК, вместо самодержавия - ВКП(б).
..........................
Спустя почти столетие мы практически каждый день узнаем все новые и новые аббры (ХХС, СБУ, АТО, ДНР...), ведь политические и НТ революции продолжаются и продолжаются.